# Съедается начало ответа от api GPT при асинхронном запросе

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, asyncio, chatgpt-api

Всем привет!
Пишу бота через aiogram и прикрутил к нему gpt, но при асинхронных запросах начало съедать начало текста. Такая штука только при асинхронном запросе, через модуль Openai. Пробовал и через aiohttp и получилось избавиться от проблемы такой, отключив stream, но хотелось бы конечно оставить возможность, получать не 1 финальный с полностью готовым текстом ответ, а много маленьких по частям. Буду благодарен за любые подсказки. Код функции, в которой идет запрос к api, прикреплю ниже... А и кстати. Съедает начало текста он не всегда. Периодически.

```
async def send_message_gpt(prompt, id, anounce):
  main_menu_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(types.KeyboardButton("Главное меню"))
  result = ""
  await bot.send_message(id, "<b>Идет обработка текста!</b>", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard)
  generate_text = await bot.send_message(id, "...", parse_mode='html')


  response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613', messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": f"{prompt}"}], stream=True)

  symbol_step = 100

  for message in response:
      try:
        result += message["choices"][0]["delta"]["content"]
        if len(result) >= symbol_step:
            await generate_text.edit_text(result)
            symbol_step += 100
    except:
        pass

  if anounce:
    new_gen_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(types.KeyboardButton("Перегенерировать текст"), types.KeyboardButton("Главное меню")).add(types.KeyboardButton("Сгенерировать Заголовок и анонс"))
  else:
    new_gen_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        types.KeyboardButton("Перегенерировать текст"), types.KeyboardButton("Главное меню"))

  await generate_text.edit_text(result)
  await bot.send_message(id, f'Текст сгенерирован!', reply_markup=new_gen_keyboard)
  await ProfilesStatesGroup.new_gen.set()

  return result
```